# Multiple Async Calls to Web API from Angular causes program hang

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have to make multiple calls to Web API from Angular.  The problem is this is causing some kind of deadlock in the thread and it is timing out return "A Task was canceled".  I tried using ConfigureAwait(false) which I found on another post, but it did not solve my issue.  In my Angular Controller, I have:

```
    function getClusterLinks(linkCode, returnString) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.returnString = returnString;
    contractorService.gethyperlink(linkCode)
    .success(function (data) {
        var vchUrl = data[0].vchUrl;
        var end = vchUrl.length;
        var docID = vchUrl.substring(vchUrl.indexOf("=") + 1, end);
        var vchLinkName = data[0].vchLinkName;
        var yay = '<a href="" ng-click="getDocumentByID(' + docID + ')">' + vchLinkName + '</a>';
        var yCode = "|Y" + linkCode + "~";
        $scope.returnString = $scope.returnString.replaceAll(yCode, yay);
        deferred.resolve();
    })
    return deferred.promise;

}
```

In my Angular Service:

```
         this.gethyperlink = function (id) {
         return $http.get('/Home/GetHyperLink?id=' + id)
     };
```

In my MVC Controller:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetHyperLink(int id)
    {
        var link = await CommonClient.GetHyperLinkByID(id);
        return Json(link, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my CommonWebApiClient:

```
        public Task<List<HyperLinkModel>> GetHyperLinkByID(int linkID)
    {
        try 
        {

            var response = PerformGet<List<HyperLinkModel>>(string.Format("api/GetMyHyperlinks/{0}", linkID.ToString()));
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

In my WebApiClientBase:

```
 protected async Task<T> PerformGet<T>(string requestUri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress })
        {
            try
            {
                AppendDefaultHeaders(client);
                var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

        }
    }
```

The line above where it hangs is:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are you calling PerformGet?

Comment: Please see my edits above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `GetHyperLinkByID` method.  The recommendation is to by asynchronous all the way through the pipeline.  Try this instead

```
    public async Task<List<HyperLinkModel>> GetHyperLinkByID(int linkID)
{
    try 
    {

        var response = await PerformGet<List<HyperLinkModel>>(string.Format("api/GetMyHyperlinks/{0}", linkID.ToString()));
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

It helps me when I do an asynchronous method to add the Async at the end of the method so I know that I the method is asynchronous and that I need to await it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I still have the same issue.